ModRewrite rule - Skip if the selector is not present
I have a situation where I need to write urls with and without selectors seperately.
for example

the URI /feeds/mydata.json should go to /content/feeds/mydata/app.json
the URI /feeds/mydata.sale.json should go to /feeds/mydata/app.sale.json
the URI /feeds/mydata.sale.big.json should go to /feeds/mydata/app.sale.big.json

What I have so far:
RewriteRule ^/feeds/([^.]*).(.*).json /content/feeds/$1/app.$2.json [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^/feeds/(.*).json /content/feeds/$1/app.json [PT,L]

the problem is the first rule rewrites even if there is no selector. so the case 1 goes from /feeds/mydata.json to /feeds/mydata/app..json
Is there a way I can state a condition to check if the selector is present.
Note there can be multiple selectors as in case 3.

The pattern ^/feeds/([^.]*).(.*).json will certainly match requests to /feeds/mydata.json. That is because your regular expression is vague, kind of:
Keep in mind that the literal dot (".") in a regular expression will match any single character. Knowing that you will understand that ([^.]*).(.*).json will indeed match mydata.json. Because "mydata" certainly is a string that starts with something that is not a dot, followed by any character, followed by any character sequence, followed by any character, followed by the literal sequence "json" ...
The regex101.com utility will help you understand and play around with the details.
Try that instead:
^/?feeds/([^.]*)\.(.+)\.json$

Though very limited, the made-with-love tool will help you quickly test your rules.
If you want to dig into the details of regular expressions there is the "standard bible" for that topic my O'Reighlly: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/
